# How to make data of a cart to increase dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, backend

I'm trying to make cart items to stack dynamically every time on function call: `addProduct()`. The data which I want to work with was captured successfully but the problem is that on each function call the quantity always remains 1.

This is the logic which I implemented:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.productItems = oldCart.productItems || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || oldCart.totalQty==0.00;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || oldCart.totalPrice==0.00;
    
    this.addProduct = function(item, id) {
        
        //let storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0}; 
        /*Using this storedItem qty: 0, price: 0 for testing*/
   
        if (!storedItem){
            storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
        }
        storedItem = {item: item, qty: storedItem.qty, price: storedItem.price}

        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        this.totalQty ++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.price;
        
        //this.productItems += storedItem;
        console.log("Product items: ",this.productItems)
        
    }

    this.generateArray = function () {
        let arr = [];
        for (let id in this.productItems) {
            arr.push(this.productItems);
        }
        return arr;
    }};
```

When I remove line: `let storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};` the result remains `NaN`. So how to solve this problem? Because the items are still at the quantity of 1 no matter how many API calls do I make.

Here is my app.post call:

```
app.post('/add-to-cart/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});

    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/products');
    const singleProduct = await data.find((product) => product._id === id)
    
    
    
    cart.addProduct(singleProduct, singleProduct._id)
    req.body.cart = cart;
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log("console log cart",cart);
    console.log(req.body);
  } 
  
  catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  
});
```

Here is my console.log result (every time the same):

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the `Cart` function seems to be fine. I'm wondering however if you're sending the correct data to your back end at each code. You could try to console log `req.body.cart` and check that it contains the previous content of the cart.

Comment: This doesn't work to me because the `item` is undefined

Comment: I want to store this in database, MongoDB collection, I wanted to do this later, just wanted to see now how it looks like in `console.log` , but can you write logic to work this out with a Mongo database?

Comment: Are you talking about you're `singleProduct` variable when you write `item` ? I don't see how the fact that cart is now a global produce this error.
I'm sorry I can't go further than giving you indications. But you are right, you should focus on having a simple working implementation before trying to deal with a database.

Comment: Yeah, it is meant as an item. But I don't need to save this to database, I firstly need to send in req.body, but I need somehow my data to overwrite the data of an old cart, and constantly needed to be overwrited, with a new method I want to store it in a database.

Comment: So I need this `new Cart` but I just need to dynamically store properties like quantity so I think I need to change whole logic in `module.exports` part, but I don't know how.

Comment: I edited my answer after reading your comments

Comment: Okay, if I remove `req.body.cart = cart;` line and use `console.log(req.body.cart)` I get the undefined, why is that? `req.body.cart` should be defined because I used this: `let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});`

Comment: `req.body` is set inside your request so you need to send your old cart as a payload when you are calling the server. The line you sent : `let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});`is only setting the cart variable

Comment: But anyways I'm getting the same result, and old cart doesn't exist, I just get the data of the new request in the API

Comment: Old cart doesn't exist cause you are not saving it anywhere as I explained previously. You must send back the content of your current cart. The server handles the cart you send, adds an item and send back the updated cart. It seems to me that we aren't getting anywhere with this thread. I hope I was of some help and I wish you good luck in the resolution of your problem

Comment: So can you write this logic? I'm not sure how to do that.